# Use of "has been"

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, passive-voice

I just want to know whether the way I used *has been* in a reply is correct. The sentence is

> The query **has been** responded as per request

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

You also need a 'to' in there somewhere, which is an obligatory preposition with some verbs of which 'respond' is one.

But 'has been responded to', when used in the passive, with no object following, can sound awkward.

I think I would say ***A response has been given to the query as requested***.

Comment: Or, of course, *The query has been answered.*

Answer (score 3):

Correctness is one things; appropriateness another. It is certainly possible to use the construction:

> <sub><sup>*SINGULAR SUBJECT*</sup></sub> has been <sub><sup>*PAST PARTICIPLE*</sup></sub>.

However, this works best when the actual agent is named, because otherwise it is an unidentifiable anonymous agent that can sound like pretentious bureaucratese.

Compare:

> It has been decided that a reply to your inquiry should be sent.

with:

> How miserably that noble author has been abused by his Translators. (*English Theography*)
>
> Your transfer request has been approved by your commanding officer.

In the first case, and in yours, there is no agent provided, a trick much beloved by bureaucrats as a distancing mechanism to deflect all responsibility.
In contrast, the second case uses passive voice without naming the agent.

The first case leaves the answer to the question “decided by whom?” unstated and hanging in the air.  Sometimes this is ok, and sometimes it is a manipulative trick.  Agent-free passives can too easily come off sounding like weasel words, especially when other pretentious weasel words like “as per” are included.

<sub>**Usage Note:** The expression *as per* is always at least one word too many: just use *per* if you really feel you must, but that is still a fairly stand-offish, high-register word.  *According to* and related terms are longer but less stuffy than *per*, and seriously less stuffy than *as per*, which sounds like some sort of writ issues by the courts.</sub>

Better to be more direct:

> We have sent you an answer to your inquiry.
>
> We have answered your inquiry by post.

This is not to say that you should always avoid *has been*. Certainly there are many occasions when it is perfectly natural and non-off-putting:

> This fabric has been treated with a flame retardant.

Even the *has been approved* example can survive without *by your commanding officer*, but it could also be written actively:

> Your command officer has approved your transfer request.

As pointed out elsewhere, the principal problem with your sentence is that your past participle is quite simply wrong.  If the verb is *respond to*, its past participle must consequently be *responded to*.

> Please respond to our second request immediately.
>
> Given that I already responded to your first request, I do not believe your request need be responded to.

But better to write this:

> Given that I already responded to your first request, I do not believe I need respond to your second.

You may also wish to consider synonyms for the verb *respond to*, many of which require no following particle, like *acknowledge* or *answer* — but not *reply to*, which still needs its *to*.